# Title Bar with Fluent Design System - UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, fluent-design

I am develop an new UWP app with Fluent Design System, and I want that my background with Acrylic material and I am using `<Grid Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBaseHighAcrylicWindowBrush}">` my I also want that the Title Bar of my UWP app be transparent (with Fluent Design System) and I am use this:

```
var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

but the minimizing, maximizing, and closing butts do not become transparent, why?

I want the title bar of my application to be the same as the Windows 10 calculator!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using properties of the `ApplicationViewTitleBar` class:

```
 var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

 // active
 view.TitleBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 8, 87, 180);
 view.TitleBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;

 // inactive  
 view.TitleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 8, 87, 180);
 view.TitleBar.InactiveForegroundColor = Colors.Black;

 // button
 view.TitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 8, 87, 180);
 view.TitleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White;

 view.TitleBar.ButtonHoverBackgroundColor = Colors.Blue;
 view.TitleBar.ButtonHoverForegroundColor = Colors.White;

 view.TitleBar.ButtonPressedBackgroundColor = Colors.Blue;
 view.TitleBar.ButtonPressedForegroundColor = Colors.White;

 view.TitleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.DarkGray;
 view.TitleBar.ButtonInactiveForegroundColor = Colors.Gray;
```

Documentation references:

1. [ApplicationViewTitleBar Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewTitleBar)
2. [Title bar customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar)

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Do I need this whole code to put the background buttons (minimizing, maximizing, and closing) in transparent?

Comment: If u just want the three buttons transparent, u can use view.TitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;

Comment: @fernandousaaa If you want to thank somebody then you should accept his answer, i.e. mark his answer as helpful.